# How to put a transparent background with carrierwave, resize_and_pad method and jpg?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rmagick

I am using Carrierwave and RMagick to upload images to my Rails application. I have a `image_uploader` like that:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # ... Other stuff ...
  process :convert => 'png'

  def filename
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.png'
  end

  # ...

  version :resized_image do
    process :resize_and_pad => [X, Y]
  end

  # ...
end
```

My problem is that when I upload a png image, the `resize_and_pad` method is adding a transparent background to fit the dimensions specified. But it when I upload a jpg image, it is being converted to png but the background is white and not transparent, maybe because the image is being converted to png after being resized and not before.

So, is there any solution to this problem? Is there any possible way to assure that `convert` method is being called before the `resize_and_pad` to add the transparent background to the resized image?

**EDIT**

I put an example to make my problem clearer:

The uploaded JPG is a normal image, for example 300px × 300px. My `resize_and_pad` method pad the image to 300px × 400px. Those 100px that I want to pad must be transparent, but due to JPG can't have transparent backgrounds, I try to convert to PNG before applying the `resize_and_pad`. My problem is that the final result is an image with white background instead of transparent background.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625066/carrierwave-rmagick-not-removing-transparency-in-convert-to-jpg

Answer (score -1):

JPG files do not support transparency, if you see a white background in a JPEG image it is because it is filled with white, therefore when your uploader process the JPEG image it faithfully converts the white background.

Comment: I know that, that's why I'm trying to convert the image to png before the resizing process. Also that fact is being specified in the docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/c/carrierwave-rails3-0.4.5/CarrierWave/RMagick.html#method-i-resize_and_pad. But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: So is what you are trying to achieve having the Resize convert the white background to transparant during the conversion?

Comment: I put an example in the question. Maybe you can understand better my problem.